# Help with seleniums carriage return

Tags: selenium

I need to select an item from a list and then simulate hitting enter in selenium code. 
I heard about using:

```
selenium.keyPressNative("\13");
```

to simulate it, but it thought that \13 was the male symbol... Anyone know the actual number? Or am i doin something silly?

Answer (score 0):

From the selenium JavaDoc on `keyPressNative()`

> @param keycode an integer keycode number corresponding to a java.awt.event.KeyEvent; note that Java keycodes are NOT the same thing as JavaScript keycodes!

13 is the JavaScript key code for the Enter key, it is not the `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` key code.

You could either switch to `keyPress()` or supply the correct key code, which I believe is `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` which is `\n`.

Comment: At this moment i realize i asked my question wrong, \n is carriage return/newline character, thats not actually what i need! What im trying to do is enter the text i want and hit "Enter" not carriage return. Hitting enter loads the details relevant to the user who's name i entered. Do you know the code for enter?

Comment: As I said in my post you need to use the key codes in java.awt.event.KeyEvent, if you look at the source of that file it lists VK_ENTER as "\n"

Comment: so i need keyPressNative("\\n")? I always associated zn as being a special char, not actually the return key.

Comment: "\\n" it says problem with input \n, and "\n" it reads as " ". (blank)